# advanced differences between ubuntu and mint

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

I really wonder how mint differs from ubuntu. I am not talking about file colors, start menu like windows or any other displays. How does it differ from ubuntu? How does file permissions change from one to another?

For now i assume that the only difference is the display(green color of mint) and slides. I have been working with both of them but it seems there is not much difference. Can you give me a detailed difference chart so that all of us can understand it in a better way? Regards.

Comment: This isn't a good question for SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no basic difference.

Both are distributions of linux, thereby, there is no difference in System level I/O, File-read, etc. When you ask for the difference in two OS, you particularly see the difference in their Kernel implementation and System calls and then you generalize them.

So, as far as file-structure, permissions etc are there, they are same (Because both are Linux).

Now, Ubuntu and Mint are both Debian based distributions. So, their basic commands, repositories, package-managers etc are also same. If two OS's which are same (like in this case, both are Linux) need to be compared, you will find major (noticeable) differences only if they are "differently based". `eg. Centos and Ubuntu`, which are Red-Hat and Debian distributions respectively, differ at command line. (But since they both are also Linux OS's, their file-system, System calls etc. remain same.)

Comment: I thought that there are some changes in both distributions but this answer clearifies my thoughts about the subject. Thanks!